# how to share a vscode dev container with someone else?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I am sharing my project (a vscode dev container) with a collaborator.

This collaborator needs my environment and certain project files.

I exported my files/environment in (1.1-2) below, but I was unable to open the new container created in (2.2) below.

#### 1. Export my stuff

1. copy the parts of my workspace that I need to share

```
rsync -av --exclude 'irrelevant_content' my_vscode_project/ my_collab_share/
```

2. backup my dev container to share

```
docker commit my_dev_container my_shared_image
```

#### 2. Test access the new container

1. start a new container using the image I just created

```
cd my_collab_share
docker run -v $pwd:/workspaces/my_vscode_project my_shared_image
Container started
```

2. Open the new container in vscode

   1. click the Docker tab
   2. click on Individual Containers -> my_shared_image ->

But 2.2.2 fails and I get the following error in the log:

```
[5084 ms] Command in container failed: mv -n /home/vscode/.vscode-server/bin/92da9481c0904c6adfe372c12da3b7748d74bdcb_1678478748544/* /home/vscode/.vscode-server/bin/92da9481c0904c6adfe372c12da3b7748d74bdcb && rmdir /home/vscode/.vscode-server/bin/92da9481c0904c6adfe372c12da3b7748d74bdcb_1678478748544
[5084 ms] rmdir: failed to remove '/home/vscode/.vscode-server/bin/92da9481c0904c6adfe372c12da3b7748d74bdcb_1678478748544': Directory not empty
[5085 ms] Exit code 1
```